# LINQ to SQL: inserting child entity fails because ID is not included in SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm doing a very simple insert into a database by assigning the child of an LINQ-to-SQL entity, but it's failing on the foreign key.

The code is:

```
var imageStripFileAltText = new ImageStripFileAltText();
imageStripFileAltText.Alt = "alt text";
imageStripFile.ImageStripFileAltText = imageStripFileAltText;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

`imageStripFile` is a custom type `ImageStripFile` with a corresponding table in the database.
`db` is a DataContext.

When I inspect `imageStripFile.ImageStripFileAltText` in the debugger, I see that it has been assigned the correct foreign key Id, that is, the primary key of `imageStripFile`. However, I get the following Exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ImageStripFileAltText_ImageStripFile". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Cms", table "dbo.ImageStripFile", column 'Id'.

Since I made sure the `ImageStripFile` with the corresponding ID exists, this baffled me, until I inspected the generated SQL:

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(4000) = 'alt text' 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ImageStripFileAltText]([Alt])
VALUES (@p0)
```

The generated SQL does not include the ID in the parameters!

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried directly assigning the foreign key ID:

```
var imageStripFileAltText =
    new ImageStripFileAltText() { ImageStripFileId = imageStripFile.Id };
```

but the result is the same.

Edit: If I remove the `IsIdentity` property from the child table's primary key (which I now believe is the correct situation), I get a different Exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'ImageStripFileId', table 'Cms.dbo.ImageStripFileAltText';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Note that this corresponds with the generated SQL as well.

Comment: Does it work if you add `dc.ImageStripFileAltText.InsertOnSubmit(imageStripFileAltText);` before your submit changes?

Comment: No, I get the exact same result.

Comment: Rather than setting the id try `imageStripFileAltText.ImageStripFile = imageStripFile;`.  Do you have multiple dataContexts (ie loading imageStripFile in one and try to save the ImageStripFileAltText in another?

Comment: Setting the parent on the child has the same result as setting the child on the parent.
I am only using one datacontext in this method.

Comment: Last suggestion. Download LinqPad (from https://www.linqpad.net/) and let it build the model from your database and try your code. If it works in LinqPad, then it would suggest there is something wrong with your model.

Comment: @sgmoore: Yes, I did this and found out the code was fine. The problem was the model built from the db did not correspond with the db the code was using. :/

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, the PK field in my table was not auto incremented i.e. IsIdentity was set to false. Try checking this in your tables.

Comment: My PK is Identity, but it is not auto-incremented, since it is a Foreign key (i.e., it exists in another table).

Comment: The PK of the table which is being referenced as FK.

Comment: Yes, that one definitely is both. It is a very old table in fact, it has been in use for years. It's only the `ImageStripFileAltText` table that's new.

Comment: did you try explicitly setting Id filed of ImageStripFile table?

Comment: Yes, but the generated SQL still doesn't include it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I was building my model on the Development Database and executing the code on the Production Database, on which the `ImageStripFileAltText` table had a slightly different scheme (probably something with IsIdentity?), since I was still tinkering with it when I wrote the code.

Long story short: the code is fine; don't be an idiot and work diligently.

Answer (score 0):

IsIdentity needs to set true of ID and set autoincremented

Comment: No not here, because it is a foreign key; its value comes from another table.